# How to close the completion tooltip, without closing the compile output pane in QtCreator

Tags: tooltip, qt-creator, usability

When I'm writing code with QtCreator (2.4.1), I'm very often in this situation: something is wrong with my code, e.g a bad argument in a constructor. The error is reported in the compile output.
Then I jump to the line to modify my code: once inside the constructor, QtCreator displays a tooltip, which most of the time, hides something on the previous lines. And most of the time, I need to read something on the previous line.  The only way to close this tooltip (with the keyboard only), is to hit ESC. By doing this, the compile output is also closed, and the geometry of the editing pane also changes, which is disorienting.
Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option in Qt Creator to deactivate automatic auto-completion.

Here are the instructions for Qt Creator 2.4.1 :

1. Select *Options...* under the *Tools* menu
2. Under *Text Editor*, choose *Completion* tab
3. Select *Manually* in the *Activate completion* dropdown menu.
4. Hit *Apply* and then *OK* to close the dialog

Now on, to invoke auto-completion, you have to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.

Comment: That's good enough for me. I also disabled "Return to editor" shortcut, to prevent ESC from closing the Compile output pane.